# PayPal shopping cart button markup error?

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

I'm getting this error message when testing my Add to Cart functionality using PayPal.

PayPal is very misleading with what fields and values I should be using. For example it says the cmd field should have _cart as value if the button is an Add to Cart, but I've found a working example using -s_xclick (which doesn't work for me).

Here is my markup:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                                <!-- Specify an Add to Cart button. -->
                                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                                <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
                                <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Two">
                                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
                                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="HY3MQABS97HT">

                                <span>£200</span><input type="hidden" name="amount" value="200">                                    <!-- <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif"alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online"> -->
                                <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="http://www.karenrothwell.com/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/addToBasketSmall.png" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
                            </form>
```

What am I missing that would cause it not work? All seems in order to me!

Answer (score 0):

The business 'HY3MQABS97HT' is invalid. Is it perhaps for a Sandbox account? Then you'll need to change https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

**Note:** The difference between _cart and _s-xclick is that _cart is used for unencrypted buttons, and _s-xclick is used for 'hosted'  buttons (details stored with PayPal).

Comment: I thought I could use my Merchant ID in place of my paypal email?

Comment: You can. The merchant ID you're using must be wrong (or it must come from a different environment; e.g. Sandbox).

Comment: no it's not from a sandbox environment. and yes the merchant id is correct. any more ideas?

Comment: HY3MQABS97HT is definitely invalid. You sure you're looking at the "Secure merchant account ID" from within the PayPal Profile?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: its the same fields that you are using, the difference is i've used my email address for business field replacing yours

Comment: the same code and just that one difference? i used my Merchant ID instead of my PayPal email. I read that it is more secure.